# Recorrer JSON en python

Tags: python, json, bottle

He realizado una peticion get con python que me devuelve este JSON, me gustaria poder recorrerlo de tal forma que se imprima mas o menos asi:

Habitacion 0: 
id: x - precio: x - camas: x - disponible: x

Habitacion 1: 
id: x - precio: x - camas: x - disponible: x

...

Muchas Gracias! .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En vez de poner la foto podrías adjuntar el "payload" del JSON? Y has intentado escribir algo de código? Si es así, nos ayudaría para poder solucionar el problema.

Comment: Está en localhost, no lo puedo poner aqui.

Comment: Siempre puedes copiarlo y pegarlo.

Answer (score 0):

¿Lo que pides es algo como esto?

```
# Cambia esto por el nombre de tu diccionario, 
# pero deja la parte de .items()
for room, data in tu_diccionario_json.items():  
    print(f"Habitacion {data[room]}: "
          f" - id: {data['id']}"
          f" - precio: {data['precio_noche']}"
          f" - camas: {data['camas']}"
          f" - disponible: {data['libre']}")
```

Basta con recorrer el diccionario en un bucle.
**NOTA:** Las [f-string](https://platzi.com/blog/f-strings-en-python/) solo funcionan en Python 3.6 o superior

**BONUS:** Puede que tengas que acceder a esa información como:

```
tu_diccionario_json['data'].items()
```